# Validating parts of a string input to make sure letters or numbers are input for certain indexes

Tags: java, string, validation, methods

Stupid title aside, I'm having trouble validating that the value "MBA222" is not allowed when inputted and values like "MB2222" are. That is to say I'm unsure of how to insure the first two characters of the String are letters and the next four are numbers. Am I perhaps using the wrong method?

```
public static String getValidMembership(String aMember){

    while(isValidMembership(aMember) == false){
        aMember = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter Membership Number");
    }
    return aMember;
}

private static boolean isValidMembership(String aMember){
    boolean result = false;

    //TODO add your code here
    try{
        if(!aMember.substring(0,1).contains("[a-zA-Z]+") &&
            !aMember.substring(2,5).contains("[0-9]+")&&
            aMember.length() != 6){
            result = false;

        }
        else{
            result = true; 
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        result = false; 
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a single regex:

```
public static boolean isValidMembership(String aMember) {
    return Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]{2}\\d{4}$", aMember);
}
```

I would recommend reading the [Javadoc for the Pattern class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) which provides a lot of details of how to use regexes.

Comment: I've updated the code to assure that it would match the start and end of the string, so this regex will match a string with a length of only 6.

Comment: @Kirk Hofmeister is there anything else you're looking for?

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: @KirkHofmeister if one of these posts has answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer so others looking over this question can quickly find the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `String`'s method `contains(...)` doesn't work with RegEx, you should use `matches(...)` for that.

To check if a `String` matches your criteria, you can use a statement like this:

```
s.matches("[A-Za-z]{2}\\d{4}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elegant and lean implementation of your `isValidMembership()` method:

```
private static boolean isValidMembership(String aMember){
    if (aMember.replaceFirst("([a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{4})", "").length() != 0) {
        return false;
    }  

    return true;
}
```

I removed your `try-catch` block because it doesn't seem necessary.

This solution uses the following regex, which you can also test by following the link given below:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}
```

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/jB1mK0/3)

Note that this regex will match two letters followed by four numbers, but the Java code imposes the additional constraint that the length of the string must be 6.

Comment: Thank you but forces beyond my control require me to have one. Thank you though for the input.

Comment: You are free to use a `try-catch` block, though you should realize it is not necessary.

Comment: Your solution will result in matching a string of the form "AA0000AA0000" because of your method of `.replaceAll`

Comment: @ParkerHoyes Good catch, I have updated the code to use `String.replaceFirst()`.  This will ensure that only string patterns which match exactly, and match only _once_, will fire as true.

Comment: @ParkerHoyes Thanks for the catch.